# How to delete all custom product attributes

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento2.4, custom-attributes, magento2.4.3

How can  delete all custom product attributes from database and keep only system attributes in Magento 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive the same by Mysql query

```
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `eav_attribute`.`entity_type_id=4` AND `eav_attribute`.`is_user_defined`=1";
```

*entity_type_id=4* for \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY

*is_user_defined=1* means that that attribute is created by user and can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try below script

$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

$eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom-attribute-code'